# way to represent a list of model in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a clean simple way to represent a view model conaining a list of a database model in a razor view?

I am currently able to get this to work but I have to give every id and name of my inputs an unique value and then loop through a `formcollection` trying to match the input's id/name to retrieve the data.

Is there a more simple/cleaner way to do this?

[image]

```
@model WorkedHoursEditorViewModel

@section header {
    <h1>@Resources.Global.Label_WorkedHours</h1>
    <a href="#" id="header-save" class="ui-btn-right">@Resources.Global.Label_Save</a>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(
        "EditReportWorkedHours",
        "Order",
        FormMethod.Post,
        new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"id", "detail-form"},
            {"class", "ui-body ui-corner-all"},
            {"data-ajax", "false"}
        }))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(q => q.Report.Id)
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d" style=" margin:0;">
        @foreach (var item in @Model.WorkDayList)
        {
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                <h3>@item.Date.DayOfWeek @item.Date.Year-@item.Date.Month-@item.Date.Day</h3>
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <label for="Hours.@item.Date.Day">@Resources.Global.Label_Hours:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <input type="text" id="Hours_@item.Date.Day" name="Hours.@item.Date.Day" value="@item.Hours" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <label for="Charged.Hours.@item.Date.Day">@Resources.Global.Label_ChargedHours:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <input type="text" id="Charged_Hours_@item.Date.Day" name="Charged.Hours.@item.Date.Day" value="@item.Charged" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <label for="Travel.Hours.@item.Date.Day">@Resources.Global.Label_TravelHours:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <input type="text" id="Travel_Hours_@item.Date.Day" name="Travel.Hours.@item.Date.Day" value="@item.Travel_Hours" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>  

            </div>
        }

    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good article about model binding and lists: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/